Python selenium send_keys not working when call called in function and loop
I Am new to python selenium. I am trying to upload csv files to a webportal. I have created the following function(s)/code to upload the file to portal.
webpage has the following code:

<span class="nobr">                                        
    <input type="file" name="csvFile" size="60" value="">
</span>



def logging_in():
    #my login code bla bla bla


def upload_file(urlname,csvfile):
    driver.get(urlname)
    #Below line not able to format correctly.
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME,'iframe')))
   if check_exists_by_tag(driver,'iframe'):
      iframe = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'iframe')
      driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
      
      WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.NAME, "csvFile")))
      if check_exists_by_Name(driver,'csvFile'):
          file_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "csvFile")
          file_input.send_keys(csvfile)
          upload_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div1/div4/div5/span/a")))
          upload_button.click()
      driver.switch_to.default_content()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging_in()
    time.sleep(2)
    
    csv_files_list = [file for file in os.listdir(inputpath) if file.endswith('.csv')]
    
    for csv_file in csv_files_list:
        uploadfile(url,inputpath+csv_file)


File Upload is working fine for the first time. During the second loop the file upload not working while at the code send_keys. I am not sure what I am missing here ?
Error Message says, upload_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div1/div4/div5/span/a")))
It was due to the file_input.send_keys(csvfile) didn't input the file to the path which I can see in the browser.
During the first execution of the loop I can see the file name in the textbox.

During the second execution of the loop I can't see the file name in the textbox.

Please post either the url or the content of that page.

This is Intranet portal. Can’t post or access by open network. I will post the Input csv File tag

It seems the issue you're encountering is due to the dynamic behavior of the webpage, where the file input element may be reset or hidden after the first upload. You can try to use driver.refresh() after the first upload to reset the page and make the file input available for next uploads.
ALso,before uploading the next file, try doing "file_input.clear()" to remove the previous file path and allow a new one.

If it is hidden I shouldn’t be able to see on the webpage. Since my upload function had ‘driver.get(surname)’ it will refresh the whole page. I don’t think so it is a previous file Issue.
